# Как добавить несколько значений в таблицу?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Есть три таблицы в базе - `Админы, Заявки, МТРы`. У одного админа множество заявок, а у одной заявки множество МТР(материально технических ресурсов)

```
public partial class Заявки
{
    public Заявки()
    {
        this.МТРы = new HashSet<МТРы>();
    }

    public int Код { get; set; }
    public string ФИО { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Код_Админа { get; set; }
    public string Наличие { get; set; }
    public virtual Админы Админы { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<МТРы> МТРы { get; set; }
}


public partial class Админы
{
    public Админы()
    {
        this.Заявки = new HashSet<Заявки>();
    }

    public int Код { get; set; }
    public string Пользователи { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Заявки> Заявки { get; set; }
}

public partial class МТРы
{
    public int Код { get; set; }
    public string Мтр { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Код_Заявки { get; set; }
    public virtual Заявки Заявки { get; set; }
}
```

Есть также listbox в котором содержится список `МТРы`. Я пытаюсь программно добавить данные

```
using (HardwareEntities db = new HardwareEntities())
{
    var admin = db.Админы.Where(x => x.Код == currentiserId).FirstOrDefault();

    db.Заявки.Add(new Заявки
    {
        ФИО = fioBox.Text,
    });

    for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        db.МТРы.Add(new МТРы { Мтр = listBox1.Items[i].ToString() });
    }
    db.Админы.Add(admin);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Если в `listbox1` элементов = 1, то все работает четко, однако если элементов несколько при сохранении выдает ошибку

```
SqlException: Не удается вставить повторяющуюся строку ключа в объект "dbo.МТРы" с уникальным индексом "KEY_МТРы_Код_Заявки". Повторяющееся значение ключа: (<NULL>).
Выполнение данной инструкции было прервано.
```

Comment: Почему-то БД считает, что ваш `public Nullable<int> Код_Заявки` должен быть уникальным, покажите настройки столбцов таблицы

Comment: ЗЫ. Почему ваши классы названы на кириллице и во множественном числе?

Comment: Перешел в c# из 1c)))  з.ы шучу - так получилось

Comment: @Андрей, https://pastebin.com/VXYLpVDz вот таблица МТРы

Comment: Добавьте авто-инкремент, если хотите, чтобы идентификаторы генерировались автоматически (id int IDENTITY(1,1)). Либо задавайте их вручную в коде.

Comment: Хм, а почему вы вставляете именно таким образом, а не через `Заявки.МТРы.Add(...)`, тогда у МТР будет правильный `Код_Заявки` автоматически? Ладно кириллица, но множественное число в имени сущности - это реально жесть, как вы вообще с этим работаете?

Comment: @Андрей, db.Заявки.МТРы.Add - вот так?

Comment: @Radzhab, нет, так: `var заявка = new Заявки { ... }; заявка.МТРы.Add(...); db.Заявки.Add(заявка);`

Comment: @Андрей, сделал вот так https://pastebin.com/jhT2GCs4 Ошибка аналогичная

Comment: @Radzhab, вы добавили автоинкремент идентификаторов в скрипт по созданию таблиц?

Comment: @Vlad, для какого поля в таблице?*

Comment: @Radzhab, для идентификатора. Т.е. "Код".

Comment: @Radzhab, вы, кстати, админа добавляете который у вас уже есть в таблице (вы же его оттуда взяли). Если вы берете сущность из таблицы, то вам ее не нужно вставлять обратно, просто редактируйте ее и применяйте изменения через `db.SaveChanges()`

Comment: @Андрей, Я админа не добавляю, эти данные статичные.  Я тут вручную пробую добавить данные и вижу странность. У меня два МТРа не могут ссылаться на одну заявку. Система говорит типа уникальные значения должны быть. Скорее всего ошибка в этом.

Comment: @Radzhab, ну а как же: `var admin = db.Админы.Where(...); ... db.Админы.Add(admin);` попробуйте убрать это: `db.Админы.Add(admin)`

Comment: @Андрей, еще вопрос. МТРы.Код_Заявки почему то уникальный - хотя я не хочу чтобы он был таким. Как исправить это*?

Comment: @Radzhab, пока хз, покажите-ка еще настройки столбцов таблицы Админы

Comment: @Radzhab, а какой подход EF используете, кстати?

Comment: @Андрей, model first. вот описание таблицы Админы https://pastebin.com/PzLrAsua

Comment: @Андрей какие будут мысли?

Comment: - Обеспечьте генерацию корректного первичного ключа при вставке записи в таблицу.
- Используйте метод AddRange для добавления множества записей.

Comment: ЕПРСТ, уж если на родном языке пишите - так языковые-то правила соблюдайте!

Comment: Сущности: Заявка, Админ, МТП. Таблицы: Заявки, Админы, МТП.

Comment: Попробуй сначала добавлять все в список, потом добавлять список в бд. С помощью `foreach` добавляешь все в какой-нибудь `список МТРы`, далее `db.МТРы.AddRange(список MРТы)`

Answer (score -2):

**1)** При неявной генерации первичного ключа в EntityFramework, для него выбирается свойство класса с названием Id, либо с названием ИмяКлассаId. В вашем случае нужно явно указать первичный ключ. Сделать это можно либо через DataAnnotation

```
[Key]
public int Код { get; set; }
```

либо через FluentApi в контексте

```
Entity<T>().HasKey(e => e.Код);
```

**2)** Проверить, установлено ли  в базе данных для первичных ключей свойство identity. Если нет то задать, либо вручную, либо через новую миграцию.

**3)** Сам код добавления нужно изменить следующим образом:

```
using (HardwareEntities db = new HardwareEntities())
{
    var admin = db.Админы.Where(x => x.Код == currentiserId).FirstOrDefault();

    // Заявку нужно вынести в отдельную переменную, 
    // для того, чтобы дальше мы могли получить ее Код.
    var заявка = new new Заявки
    {
        ФИО = fioBox.Text
    };

    db.Заявки.Add(заявка);

    // Сохраняем изменения, для того, 
    // база данных сгенерировала уникальный Id(Код) заявки.
    db.SaveChanges();

    // Мне удобнее с foreach
    foreach (var мтр in listBox1.Items)
    {
        db.МТРы.Add(new МТРы
        {
            Мтр = мтр.ToString(),
            // Добавляем код заявки к Мтр
            Код_Заявки = заявка.Код
        });
    }

    db.Админы.Add(admin);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```